# store image in collectionFs

Tags: file-upload, meteor

I have successfully created entries in the mongoDb from the uploading of files but something is not right.

When a PDF is uploaded the data attribute of the Mongo Document contains lots of data, but for JPG files it contains very little:

```
{ "files_id" : "KYMu7tDSEerKtocCK", "n" : 0, "data" : "ÿØÿà", "_id" : "zWie2w64SEQvPQSi6" }
{ "files_id" : "KYMu7tDSEerKtocCK", "n" : 1, "data" : "_×ü", "_id" : "i2D2g7siB2NsHsw3P" }
```

These are the two chunks for a 428KB jpeg file. Whereas this is the entry for a 308KB PDF:

```
{ "files_id" : "fPMCentq3zdqmt3K9", "n" : 0, "data" : "%PDF-1.3\r%âãÏÓ\n1 0 obj\n<< \n/Creator (Canon )\n/CreationDate (D:20090321174932+01'00')\n/Producer ( )\n>> \nendobj\n2 0 obj\n<< /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /Width 620 /Height 877 \n/BitsPerComponent 8 /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB\n/Filter /DCTDecode /Length 28744 >> \nstream\nÿØÿà", "_id" : "n9qiR2boCYGfzaLYn" }
{ "files_id" : "fPMCentq3zdqmt3K9", "n" : 1, "data" : "> Tj\n1 0 0 1 68.64 318.72 Tm\n<646520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 83.04 319.68 Tm\n<706572736F6E6E657320> Tj\n1 0 0 1 132.00 317.28 Tm\n<656E20> Tj\n1 0 0 1 145.92 316.80 Tm\n<6D656E61676520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 184.80 316.32 Tm\n<64616E7320> Tj\n1 0 0 1 208.32 316.80 Tm\n<726C74756620> Tj\n1 0 0 1 231.84 315.84 Tm\n<726F67656D656E7420> Tj\n1 0 0 1 297.12 314.88 Tm\n<4E62726520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 321.60 313.92 Tm\n<646520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 335.52 315.36 Tm\n<70657273276E6E654520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 384.96 312.96 Tm\n<656E20> Tj\n1 0 0 1 398.88 312.96 Tm\n<6D2E6E61676520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 437.76 312.00 Tm\n<64616E7320> Tj\n1 0 0 1 461.76 312.00 Tm\n<6675747572726F67656D656E74> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n/F3 12.0 Tf\n1 0 0 1 44.64 281.28 Tm\n<4E62726520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 69.12 281.28 Tm\n<646520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 83.52 282.24 Tm\n<70696563657320> Tj\n1 0 0 1 114.24 280.32 Tm\n<61637475656C6C6545> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n1 0 0 1 44.16 263.52 Tm\n<473672456E636520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 86.40 262.56 Tm\n<45636C75656C6C65> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n1 0 0 1 44.64 244.80 Tm\n<4C6779657220> Tj\n1 0 0 1 72.96 244.32 Tm\n<61637475656C5F> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n1 0 0 1 44.16 214.08 Tm\n<456E66616E74287329> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n1 0 0 1 44.64 195.84 Tm\n<5072646E6F6D20> Tj\n1 0 0 1 83.04 195.36 Tm\n<657420> Tj\n1 0 0 1 94.08 194.88 Tm\n<6461746520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 115.68 194.40 Tm\n<646520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 129.60 194.40 Tm\n<6E61697365656E6365> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n/F3 13.0 Tf\n1 0 0 1 297.60 351.84 Tm\n<4E2720> Tj\n1 0 0 1 311.04 351.84 Tm\n<646520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 324.96 351.36 Tm\n<74656C2E20> Tj\n1 0 0 1 341.76 353.28 Tm\n<7072697641> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n/F3 12.0 Tf\n1 0 0 1 297.12 333.60 Tm\n<4E2720> Tj\n1 0 0 1 311.04 333.12 Tm\n<646520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 324.96 333.12 Tm\n<74366C2E20> Tj\n1 0 0 1 341.28 333.60 Tm\n<70726F6620> Tj\n1 0 0 1 361.44 330.24 Tm\n<5F> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n1 0 0 1 297.12 277.44 Tm\n<4E62726520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 321.12 276.96 Tm\n<648020> Tj\n1 0 0 1 335.52 278.40 Tm\n<70696263807320> Tj\n1 0 0 1 367.20 276.48 Tm\n<616F7475656C6C65732D5F5F3A> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n/F3 13.0 Tf\n1 0 0 1 296.64 259.68 Tm\n<476472616E636520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 337.92 258.72 Tm\n<61637475656C74652D20> Tj\n1 0 0 1 452.64 254.88 Tm\n<5F> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n/F3 11.0 Tf\n1 0 0 1 297.12 241.44 Tm\n<4C6F79656620> Tj\n1 0 0 1 324.96 240.48 Tm\n<42637475656C20> Tj\n1 0 0 1 355.68 238.56 Tm\n<5F> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n/F3 12.0 Tf\n1 0 0 1 297.12 209.76 Tm\n<456E66616874287329> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n1 0 0 1 297.12 192.00 Tm\n<5072366E6F6D20> Tj\n1 0 0 1 334.56 191.52 Tm\n<657420> Tj\n1 0 0 1 346.08 191.52 Tm\n<64656C462E2E6320> Tj\n1 0 0 1 382.08 190.56 Tm\n<6E61697373616E6365> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n1 0 0 1 44.16 128.16 Tm\n<41757472657320> Tj\n1 0 0 1 79.68 128.64 Tm\n<706572736F6E6E656120> Tj\n1 0 0 1 131.52 127.20 Tm\n<766976456E6C20> Tj\n1 0 0 1 163.68 126.72 Tm\n<64616E7320> Tj\n1 0 0 1 189.60 126.24 Tm\n<6C6520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 201.12 125.76 Tm\n<6D366E61676520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 248.64 125.76 Tm\n<4574616C20> Tj\n1 0 0 1 269.28 125.28 Tm\n<636976696C> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n1 0 0 1 378.72 122.88 Tm\n<4461746520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 401.76 122.40 Tm\n<646520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 416.16 122.40 Tm\n<6E61693673616E636F> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n1 0 0 1 378.24 105.12 Tm\n<526576656E7520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 414.72 104.16 Tm\n<62727574> Tj\n0.48 Tc\n1 0 0 1 44.16 78.72 Tm\n<416E696D61757820> Tj\n1 0 0 1 89.76 78.24 Tm\n<766979616E6920> Tj\n1 0 0 1 120.96 77.76 Tm\n<64616E7320> Tj\n1 0 0 1 147.36 77.28 Tm\n<6C6520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 158.40 76.80 Tm\n<6D456E73676520> Tj\n1 0 0 1 216.00 76.32 Tm\n<47656E7265> Tj\n0.00 Tc\n/F3 13.0 Tf\n1 0 0 1 249.12 107.04 Tm\n<456D706C6F79657572> Tj\n0.00 Tc\n1 0 0 1 378.24 73.92 Tm\n<4E6F6D627265> Tj\nET\n\nendstream\nendobj\n94 0 obj\n<< /Length 27 >> \nstream\n% CANON_PFINF_TYPE2_TEXTON\n\nendstream\nendobj\n95 0 obj\n<< /Length 2831 >> \nstream\nq\n595.20 0 0 841.92 0.00 0.00 cm\n/Obj51 Do\nQ\nq\n0.173 0.090 0.184 rg\n441.60 0 0 756.48 19.20 73.92 cm\n/Obj52 Do\nQ\nq\n0.137 0.059 0.149 rg\n303.36 0 0 19.20 203.52 772.80 cm\n/Obj53 Do\nQ\nq\n0.494 0.329 0.576 rg\n303.36 0 0 19.20 203.52 772.80 cm\n/Obj54 Do\nQ\nq\n0.416 0.400 0.620 rg\n253.44 0 0 104.64 326.40 680.64 cm\n/Obj55 Do\nQ\nq\n0.137 0.059 0.149 rg\n226.56 0 0 57.60 172.80 650.88 cm\n/Obj56 Do\nQ\nq\n0.282 0.239 0.506 rg\n226.56 0 0 57.60 172.80 650.88 cm\n/Obj57 Do\nQ\nq\n0.169 0.090 0.180 rg\n84.48 0 0 27.84 42.24 503.04 cm\n/Obj58 Do\nQ\nq\n0.161 0.063 0.282 rg\n84.48 0 0 27.84 42.24 503.04 cm\n/Obj59 Do\nQ\nq\n0.188 0.110 0.200 rg\n230.40 0 0 17.28 295.68 491.52 cm\n/Obj60 Do\nQ\nq\n0.298 0.078 0.282 rg\n230.40 0 0 17.28 295.68 491.52 cm\n/Obj61 Do\nQ\nq\n0.522 0.569 0.678 rg\n230.40 0 0 17.28 295.68 491.52 cm\n/Obj62 Do\nQ\nq\n0.180 0.102 0.192 rg\n149.76 0 0 14.40 295.68 476.16 cm\n/Obj63 Do\nQ\nq\n0.463 0.467 0.714 rg\n149.76 0 0 14.40 295.68 476.16 cm\n/Obj64 Do\nQ\nq\n0.165 0.086 0.176 rg\n80.64 0 0 12.48 42.24 463.68 cm\n/Obj65 Do\nQ\nq\n0.114 0.082 0.278 rg\n80.64 0 0 12.48 42.24 463.68 cm\n/Obj66 Do\nQ\nq\n0.173 0.094 0.184 rg\n84.48 0 0 11.52 42.24 371.52 cm\n/Obj67 Do\nQ\nq\n0.153 0.129 0.263 rg\n84.48 0 0 11.52 42.24 371.52 cm\n/Obj68 Do\nQ\nq\n0.227 0.149 0.239 rg\n165.12 0 0 31.68 42.24 333.12 cm\n/Obj69 Do\nQ\nq\n0.220 0.102 0.455 rg\n165.12 0 0 31.68 42.24 333.12 cm\n/Obj70 Do\nQ\nq\n0.180 0.102 0.192 rg\n76.80 0 0 48.00 295.68 406.08 cm\n/Obj71 Do\nQ\nq\n0.027 0.063 0.239 rg\n76.80 0 0 48.00 295.68 406.08 cm\n/Obj72 Do\nQ\nq\n0.184 0.106 0.196 rg\n84.48 0 0 11.52 295.68 367.68 cm\n/Obj73 Do\nQ\nq\n0.129 0.098 0.294 rg\n84.48 0 0 11.52 295.68 367.68 cm\n/Obj74 Do\nQ\nq\n0.067 0.035 0.231 rg\n330.24 0 0 11.52 195.84 394.56 cm\n/Obj75 Do\nQ\nq\n0.369 0.149 0.353 rg\n122.88 0 0 7.68 145.92 387.84 cm\n/Obj76 Do\nQ\nq\n0.122 0.090 0.286 rg\n122.88 0 0 7.68 145.92 387.84 cm\n/Obj77 Do\nQ\nq\n0.506 0.302 0.812 rg\n122.88 0 0 7.68 145.92 387.84 cm\n/Obj78 Do\nQ\nq\n0.188 0.110 0.200 rg\n483.84 0 0 18.24 42.24 309.12 cm\n/Obj79 Do\nQ\nq\n0.110 0.078 0.275 rg\n483.84 0 0 18.24 42.24 309.12 cm\n/Obj80 Do\nQ\nq\n0.176 0.098 0.188 rg\n111.36 0 0 48.00 42.24 242.88 cm\n/Obj81 Do\nQ\nq\n0.275 0.125 0.278 rg\n111.36 0 0 48.00 42.24 242.88 cm\n/Obj82 Do\nQ\nq\n0.161 0.082 0.173 rg\n134.40 0 0 27.84 42.24 194.88 cm\n/Obj83 Do\nQ\nq\n0.200 0.102 0.322 rg\n134.40 0 0 27.84 42.24 194.88 cm\n/Obj84 Do\nQ\nq\n0.184 0.106 0.196 rg\n230.40 0 0 15.36 295.68 345.60 cm\n/Obj85 Do\nQ\nq\n0.510 0.612 0.765 rg\n230.40 0 0 15.36 295.68 345.60 cm\n/Obj86 Do\nQ\nq\n0.196 g\n92.16 0 0 12.48 295.68 330.24 cm\n/Obj87 Do\nQ\nq\n0.180 0.102 0.192 rg\n92.16 0 0 12.48 295.68 330.24 cm\n/Obj88 Do\nQ\nq\n0.490 0.525 0.702 rg\n92.16 0 0 12.48 295.68 330.24 cm\n/Obj89 Do\nQ\nq\n0.165 0.086 0.176 rg\n153.60 0 0 11.52 295.68 239.04 cm\n/Obj90 Do\nQ\nq\n0.357 0.114 0.075 rg\n153.60 0 0 11.52 295.68 239.04 cm\n/Obj91 Do\nQ\nq\n0.188 0.090 0.310 rg\n153.60 0 0 11.52 295.68 239.04 cm\n/Obj92 Do\nQ\n\nendstream\nendobj\n96 0 obj\n<< \n/Type /Page \n/MediaBox [ 0 0 595.20 841.92 ] \n/Parent 12 0 R \n/Resources << /Font << /F3 8 0 R >> /XObject << /Obj51 51 0 R /Obj52 52 0 R /Obj53 53 0 R /Obj54 54 0 R /Obj55 55 0 R /Obj56 56 0 R /Obj57 57 0 R /Obj58 58 0 R /Obj59 59 0 R /Obj60 60 0 R /Obj61 61 0 R /Obj62 62 0 R /Obj63 63 0 R /Obj64 64 0 R /Obj65 65 0 R /Obj66 66 0 R /Obj67 67 0 R /Obj68 68 0 R /Obj69 69 0 R /Obj70 70 0 R /Obj71 71 0 R /Obj72 72 0 R /Obj73 73 0 R /Obj74 74 0 R /Obj75 75 0 R /Obj76 76 0 R /Obj77 77 0 R /Obj78 78 0 R /Obj79 79 0 R /Obj80 80 0 R /Obj81 81 0 R /Obj82 82 0 R /Obj83 83 0 R /Obj84 84 0 R /Obj85 85 0 R /Obj86 86 0 R /Obj87 87 0 R /Obj88 88 0 R /Obj89 89 0 R /Obj90 90 0 R /Obj91 91 0 R /Obj92 92 0 R >> /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ] >> \n/Contents [ 94 0 R 95 0 R 93 0 R ] \n>> \nendobj\n97 0 obj\n<< /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /Width 620 /Height 877 \n/BitsPerComponent 8 /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB\n/Filter /DCTDecode /Length 23332 >> \nstream\nÿØÿà", "_id" : "Xc5vW38g9E53Tptqy" }
```

it is obvious that the String data from the PDF gets stored whereas the binary data from the jpeg is missing.

This is the code to upload the files (same button for all uploads):

```
Template.loadImages.events({
   "change .file-upload-input": function (event, template) {
      var func = this;
      var files = event.currentTarget.files;
      _.each(files, function (file, idx) {
         ImageFiles.storeFile(file);
      });

   }
})
```

thank you for your support.

Comment: it appears that the binary data is stored somewhere else. because it can be retrieved

Comment: @dr-grob a bit offtopic, but you could use:
`ImageFiles.storeFiles(files);`
instead of
`_.each(files, function (file, idx) {
         ImageFiles.storeFile(file);
      });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never tried this so its a bit of a shot in the dark.

Have your image tag in your html

```
<template name="image">
    <img src="{{imgdata}}" />
</template>
```

and your JS

```
Template.image.imgdata = function() {
    return Session.get("imgdata")
}

Template.image.created = function() {
    ImageFiles.retrieveBlob("<YOUR IMAGE ID>", function(fileItem) {
        if (fileItem.blob) {
            //Really easy but a bit sketchy on browser support
            Session.set("imgdata", URL.createObjectURL(fileItem.blob));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the code. The question is misleading. My issue is actually to store the image. The blob comes back empty